# 2 dimensional MUI Grid Layout with truncation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flexbox, material-ui

I'm using Material UI v5 for layouting. I don't know how to truncate a string within a 2 dimensional Grid layout (within a Dialog).

I want to create a file upload component, with the following layout:

[image]

I can create a 1 dimensional Grid layout with truncation:

[image]

With the following code:

```ts
export function App() {
    return (
        <Dialog open={true} fullWidth maxWidth={"xs"}>
            <DialogContent>
                <Grid container columnSpacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs zeroMinWidth>
                        <Typography noWrap>
                            long filename which needs to be truncated
                            long filename which needs to be truncated
                        </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={"auto"}>
                        <Typography>100%</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

When I add another dimension for the LinearProgress indicator, I get an overflow:

[image]

That's how far I've come so far:

```ts
export function App() {
    return (
        <Dialog open={true} fullWidth maxWidth={"xs"}>
            <DialogContent>
                <Grid container direction={"column"}>
                    <Grid item>
                        <Grid container columnSpacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs zeroMinWidth>
                                <Typography noWrap>
                                    long filename which needs to be truncated
                                    long filename which needs to be truncated
                                </Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={"auto"}>
                                <Typography>100%</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                        <LinearProgress/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

I suppose that the overflow is exactly the length of the Typography component. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why you are repeating `long filename which needs to be truncated ` in **Typography**

Comment: So the string is long enough. It's just an arbitrary sequence of chars.

Comment: So you just want **overflow** to be disabled no matter how much the string is tall ?

Comment: Yes, with MUI properties.

Comment: Can you not do `sx={{overflow: "hidden"}}` on wherever the overflow is coming from?

Comment: No. That is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did get fixed with [GridV2](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid2/) which currently (V5) is marked as unstable and will replace the old grid in V6.

```
import Grid2 from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2'

export function App() {
    return (
            <Dialog open fullWidth maxWidth={"xs"}>
                <DialogContent>
                    <Grid2 container direction={"column"} wrap={"nowrap"}>
                        <Grid2>
                            <Grid2 container columnSpacing={2}>
                                <Grid2 xs>
                                    <Typography noWrap>
                                        long filename which needs to be truncated
                                        long filename which needs to be truncated
                                    </Typography>
                                </Grid2>
                                <Grid2 xs={"auto"}>
                                    <Typography>100%</Typography>
                                </Grid2>
                            </Grid2>
                        </Grid2>
                        <Grid2>
                            <LinearProgress/>
                        </Grid2>
                    </Grid2>
                </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the **overflow** to be `hidden` and make your **textOverflow** `ellipsis`  with changing **Typography** :

```
<Typography noWrap>
                                    long filename which needs to be truncated
                                    long filename which needs to be truncated
                                </Typography>
```

**to :**

```
<Typography
                  noWrap
                  sx={{ textOverflow: "ellipsis", overflow: "hidden" }}
                >
                  long filename which needs to be truncated long filename which
                  needs to be truncated
                </Typography>
```

But this can't be applied unless you provide the **Grid** a width property . like this  : `<Grid container columnSpacing={2} style={{ width: 200 }}>`
Your component should be like this  :

```
import * as React from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import LinearProgress from "@mui/material/LinearProgress";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

function App() {
  return (
    <Dialog open={true} fullWidth maxWidth={"xs"}>
      <DialogContent>
        <Grid container direction={"column"}>
          <Grid item>
            <Grid container columnSpacing={2} style={{ width: 200 }}>
              <Grid item xs zeroMinWidth>
                <Typography
                  noWrap
                  sx={{ textOverflow: "ellipsis", overflow: "hidden" }}
                >
                  long filename which needs to be truncated long filename which
                  needs to be truncated
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={"auto"}>
                <Typography>100%</Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <LinearProgress />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-72s5v5?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I do need an ellipsis. See the three dots in my first screenshot example.

Comment: I updated the code now it should work with ellipsis text overflow!

Comment: Yes, but you assigned a width to the container and it's no longer flexible. That's not what I want. I did achive that with only properties built into mui and no sx properties. I do think that that container's width is the problem.

Comment: You cannot get an ellipsis text without setting a width as far as I know  so you have one coice this one provided in my answer or have a text not ellipsis

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781860/css-grids-and-text-overflow-ellipsis

That is how you do it in plain css grid. But I'm not able to handle it with MUI.

Comment: I'm sorry tried my best that's all I came up with !